# Converting Grayscale Images to Colormap in Swift/iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, visualization, coreml

I have a 512x512 grayscale image (or MultiArray) which is the output of a CoreML depth estimation model.

In Python, one can use Matplotlib or other packages to visualise grayscale images in different colormaps, like so:

[Grayscale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeXr6.png)

[Magma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEXsF.png)

[Images from https://ai.googleblog.com/2019/08/turbo-improved-rainbow-colormap-for.html]

I was wondering if there was any way to take said output and present it as a cmap in Swift/iOS?

Answer (score 0):

If you make the model output an image, you get a CVPixelBuffer object. This is easy enough to draw on the screen by converting it to a CIImage and then a CGImage.

If you want to draw it with a colormap, you'll have to replace each of the grayscale values with a color manually. One way to do this is to output an MLMultiArray and loop through each of the output values, and use a lookup table for the colors. A quicker way is to do this in a Metal compute shader.